Can't upload to cloud bucket due to image Band
So I'm trying to export the HM map to my cloud bucket with this code:
var dataset = ee.Image("projects/sat-io/open-datasets/GHM/ghm_v15_2017_300_60land");


// Convert the floating-point band to integer values.
var convertedDataset = dataset.select('constant')

var visualization = {
  bands: "constant",
  min: 0,
  max: 1, // Adjust the maximum value based on your data range
  palette: ['0c0c0c', '071aff', 'ff0000', 'ffbd03', 'fbff05', 'fffdfd']
};


//Map.centerObject(convertedDataset);

Map.addLayer(convertedDataset, visualization, 'Human modification');

// Define an export region.
var exportRegion = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([115.0, 4.0, 127.0, 21.0]);
Map.centerObject(exportRegion);
Map.addLayer(exportRegion, {}, 'exportRegion');

// Export the visualization image as map tiles.
Export.map.toCloudStorage({
  // All tiles that intersect the region get exported in their entirety.
  // Clip the image to prevent low resolution tiles from appearing outside
  // of the region.
  image: convertedDataset.clip(exportRegion),
  description: 'ghm_2017',
  bucket: 'ghm_2017',
  maxZoom: 13,
  region: exportRegion
});

When I try to export it to my bucket it won't proceed since the "constant" band is a float and I get this error:

Error: Image to render must have integer-valued bands, but band
"constant" is floating-point. (Error code: 3)

Is there any workaround here? I tried converting the bands to an integer but of course the visualization got messed up.

I was able to fix this by changing the min and max of the visualization parameters which allowed me to convert the bands to integers:
var convertedDataset = dataset.select('gHM').multiply(100).toInt();

var visualization = {
  bands: ['gHM'],
  min: 0,
  max: 100, // Adjust the maximum value based on your data range
  palette: ['0c0c0c', '071aff', 'ff0000', 'ffbd03', 'fbff05', 'fffdfd']
};

